# simulate http request connection close Vertx HttpServerRequest

Tags: java, servlets, java-8, httpwebrequest, vert.x

It seems a stupid case but I want to simulate http request connection close, and for now I could not find the way to do it.

In my server mock  I implement this code

```
   private JsonObject setStatus(HttpServerRequest req, JsonObject content) {
    int status = getStatus();
    if (status == 499) {
        req.response()
           .close();
    } else {
        req.response()
           .setStatusCode(status);
    }
    return content;
}
```

Where I can specify if I want to make my server mock to close the connection.

But even doing that I still receive 200.

Any idea or suggestion?

Regards.

**SOLUTION:**

req.getNetSocket().close